# Python user input via popup without external library

Tags: python, input, popupwindow

i am trying to take user inputs in a popup and i have tried so many ways i.e.  external libraries of python that works with GUI  (tkinter, pyqt, easygui etc. etc. etc.)

Is there any way to do the same without such GUI library ???

And the reason i want to avoid these GUI lib is:  i want to use this feature on multiuser web application running on linux remote server,  and there is problem of DISPLAY variable on it.

If anyone going to suggest for this DISPLAY error solution with ssh X forwarding, then as i said its multi user web application,  how would it be possible to forward DISPLAY to multiple users  ???

I will be glad if i can find the answer of first question of having a solution to do without any external GUI lib .... thanks

Comment: [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) is part of the standard library; so it's not something external.

Comment: I suppose you cannot do that, there is no built-in python method to show the popup. You have to use library. Tkinter is the standard library comes built-in with python, so it is best to use it.

Comment: I think the core problem you'll have is that a popup window is, by definition, a GUI item. You're essentially asking "how do I show a GUI without a GUI?". On the other other hand, there's a lot of information missing from your question. Where does the python run (what machine and in what process)? Where should the popup show (are you expecting it to appear in a web browser somehow)? What are the users specifically looking at (and using what software)? How do the users access it?

Comment: If you are doing this on a web server, your only choice is to use web technologies. You can't display a GUI via a webserver.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments .... so let me ask little more for more clarification

I am trying to use tkinter lib on a web server for a web based application (Odoo) and when i run a tkinter code, i am getting problem of DISPLAY variable. i tried so many commands i found for the same but none of them solved my problem.   I want to open popup in browser on a web server and the web server is hosted on linux ubuntu 20.04    .... i don't know how to solve this problem for a linux remote web server

Comment: Unless the Python is running in the browser (very unlikely) then you can't show a popup in the browser via Python. I assume your Python code is running on the webserver to generate the page that is sent to the browser? That's a much more likely scenario. Your DISPLAY issue is probably because your webserver is running on a machine that doesn't have a desktop environment installed, which is both common and expected. If you want user input then you'll have to show them a webpage that asks for their input. The page could show or simulate a popup, but that's not from Python.

Comment: (Assuming Odoo haven't done something massively unusual.)